# How does Spring-Boot turns the Id parameter received from request into an Entity

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I was writing Mapping methods the following way:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "whatever")
public Response methodName(@RequestParam Integer id) { 
   ...
   Entity entity = repository.findById(id).orElse(null);
}
```

And it worked fine, but today I tried this:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "whatever")
public Response methodName(@RequestParam(name="id", required = false) Entity entity) { 
   ...
   //Entity entity = repository.findById(id).orElse(null); <- not needed anymore
}
```

The second method somehow gets that `id` parameter and searches for the entity in the database and then retrieves it, and I'd like to know how it does that.

Comment: Not sure I understand - you are passing in an Entity in the second method where as in the first you are passing in an ID to perform a lookup in the database. They are fundamentally different. In the second, you get what you put in.

Comment: Both of these methods are receiving the same parameter, an `id` which corresponds to the primary key of that entity. In the first one, the `id` was received as an Integer and then I had to manually search for that entity in the database. In the second method, instead of taking that parameter as an Integer, I tried to use the Entity that I needed, and Spring-Boot automatically searched for that entry in the database and fetched it based on the `id`. And I'm trying to understand how it can do that.